# Losing Stored data when moving between Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Regards,Please look at my Code and help me to find error.

Code:

Main Activity Class(Button on Click method):

```
public void editm(View w) {
    /*this method called when i click on Profile button that is on MainActivity(A)*/
    Intent pro=new Intent(MainActivity.this,profile.class);
    startActivity(new Intent(pro));
}
```

Intent Class:

```
public class profile extends Activity
{
    String ptrm;
    View v=null;
    pdatabasehelper phelper;
    EditText ed1;
    EditText ed2;
    EditText ed3;
    EditText ed4;
    EditText ed5;
    EditText ed6;
    TextView ptn;
    TextView kt0;
    TextView kt1;
    TextView kt2;
    TextView kt3;
    TextView kt4;
    TextView kt5;
    TextView kt6;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profilec);
        pshow(v);
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "helloo new", 10).show();
    }

    public void pshow(View w) {
        //this method called to fetch out the database values
        onStartp();
        onstart();
        Boolean flag=false;
        try {
            flag=phelper.pshowrecord(ptrm);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SOme display error", 20).show();
        }
        if(flag==true) {
            kt1.setText(phelper.name);
            kt2.setText(phelper.guardian);
            kt3.setText(phelper.number);
            kt4.setText(phelper.address);
            kt5.setText(phelper.medical);
            kt6.setText(phelper.another);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Add a Contact", 50).show();
        }
    }

    public void pbackmeth(View w) {
        /* this method called when i move back from edit activity(C)
         * to profile activity(B)
         */
        setContentView(R.layout.profilec);
        pshow(v);
    }

    public void calledit(View w)
    {
        // this method called when i click on edit button,which is
        // there below the profile.
        setContentView(R.layout.editc);
    }

    public void onStartp() {
        kt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext3);
        kt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext5);
        kt3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext7);
        kt4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext9);
        kt5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext11);
        kt6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptext13);
    }

    public void onstart() {

        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jname);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText1);
        ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText2);
        ed4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText3);
        ed5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jeditText4);
        ed6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jaeditText1);
        ptn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jprofile);
        phelper=new pdatabasehelper(this);
    }

    public void savemethj(View w)
    {
        // this method called when i click on Save button which is
        // in activity(C).
        onstart();

        long a;

        ptrm=ptn.getText().toString();

        String edt1=ed1.getText().toString();
        String edt2=ed2.getText().toString();

        String edt3=ed3.getText().toString();
        String edt4=ed4.getText().toString();

        String edt5=ed5.getText().toString();
        String edt6=ed6.getText().toString();

        try {
            a=phelper.insertpro(ptrm,edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4, edt5, edt6);

            if(a>=1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),a+ "Record Successfully Saved", 30).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Not Saved", 30).show();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Errrrrrrrrrrr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Database class:

```
public class pdatabasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    final static String databasename="demop";
    final static int databaseversion=1;
    String name,guardian,number,address,medical,another=null;

    public pdatabasehelper(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx,databasename,null,databaseversion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            Log.d("tag4545","database");
            db.execSQL("create table mypro(id text,name text,guardian text,number text,address text,medical text,another text)");
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("drop table if Exists mypic");
        //  db.execSQL("drop table if Exists emer");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long insertpro(String id,String e1,String e2,String e3,String e4,String e5,String e6)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase base=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
        byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img);
        value.put("id", id);
        value.put("name", e1);
        value.put("guardian", e2);
        value.put("number", e3);
        value.put("address", e4);
        value.put("medical", e5);
        value.put("another", e6);

        long a=base.insert("mypro",null,value);

        return a;
    }

    public boolean pshowrecord(String id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase base=getWritableDatabase();
        try
        {
            Cursor cs=base.query("mypro", new String[]{"name","guardian","number","address","medical","another"},"id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);

            if(cs!=null) {

                cs.moveToFirst();
                 Log.d("Big Error"," Programe Stop");
                name=cs.getString(0);
                guardian=cs.getString(1);
                number=cs.getString(2);
                address=cs.getString(3);
                medical=cs.getString(4);
                another=cs.getString(5);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void deleterecord(String pe_id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase base=getWritableDatabase();
        base.delete("mypro","id=?",new String[]{pe_id});
    }
}
```

I want everytime my intenactivity(Activity B or profile) called through MainActivity Button(Profile) or Activity C button(Back to profile) then i get all values from database to show it on Activity B or profile.

I am getting error where i print  "Log.d("Big Error"," Programe Stop");" in pshowrecord(String id). But when i entered value in Edit-profile that is when i edit profile values and move back to profile then this method work alright. but when i called it when i start my application again and click on profile button in first activity i.e main activity then this Log is being generated and Application Stop working even if i had the values in database because it is shown when i clicked on button "Back to profile".

Please help,I need this code after one day. Thank you

Xml Codes:

MainActivity xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
   android:background="@drawable/gb28"
  >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="edit"
        android:onClick="editm" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

profile xml code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gb2"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ptext1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="PROFILE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ptext2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext2"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:minHeight="20dp"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />

            <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="guardian"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext3"


        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />
                    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext4"


        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />
                            <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Cell Number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext5"


        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />
                                    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext6"


        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Address"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext7"


        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />
                <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext8"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:minHeight="20dp"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />
                        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ptext10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Medical Problem"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ptext9"


        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
        />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ptext11"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_below="@id/ptext10"
                             android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:minHeight="20dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ptext12"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_below="@id/ptext11"
                           android:text="Another Description"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ptext13"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_below="@id/ptext12"
                             android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                           android:isScrollContainer="true"
                           android:minHeight="20dp"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />
                        <Button 
                            android:id="@+id/peditb"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/ptext13"
                            android:text="Edit Profile"
                            android:onClick="calledit"
                            />
        </RelativeLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

edit activity xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 

  android:background="@drawable/gb2"
 >
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/gb2"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jprofile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="PROFILE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/jtextView5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/jeditText2"
         android:layout_below="@+id/jeditText2"
         android:text="Address"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/jeditText3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/jtextView5"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/jtextView5"
         android:ems="10"
         android:hint="Home_Address"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:minHeight="20dp"
          />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/jtextView6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/jeditText3"
         android:text="Medical Problem"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/jeditText4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/jtextView6"
         android:ems="10"
         android:hint="Medical Problems or Alergies"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
          />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/jtextView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/jtextView6"
         android:layout_below="@+id/jtextView1"
         android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
         android:text="Name"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />


     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/jtextView4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/jtextView3"
         android:layout_below="@+id/jeditText1"
         android:text="Cell Number"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/jeditText2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/jname"
         android:layout_below="@+id/jtextView4"
         android:ems="10"
         android:hint="Number"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:minHeight="20dp" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/jphoto"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/jeditText2"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/jeditText2"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/jprofile"
          android:text="Take Photo" 
          android:onClick="cammethod"
          />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/jname"
          android:layout_width="170dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/jtextView6"
          android:layout_below="@+id/jtextView2"
          android:ems="10"
          android:hint="Enter_Name"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:isScrollContainer="true"
          android:minHeight="20dp" >

          <requestFocus />
      </EditText>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/jtextView3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/jname"
          android:text="Guardian"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/jeditText1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/jeditText2"
          android:layout_below="@+id/jtextView3"
          android:ems="10"
          android:hint="Guardian Name"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:isScrollContainer="true"
          android:minHeight="20dp" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/jatextView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/jeditText4"
          android:text="Another Description"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/jaeditText1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/jatextView1"
          android:ems="10"
          android:hint="Another Description"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:isScrollContainer="true"
          android:minHeight="20dp" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/jsaveb"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/jtextView5"
          android:layout_below="@+id/jaeditText1"
          android:onClick="savemethj"
          android:text="Save" />

      <Button 
           android:id="@+id/jback"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/jsaveb"
          android:layout_below="@+id/jaeditText1"
          android:onClick="pbackmeth"
          android:text="Back to Profile" />
          />

  </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I rally didn't understand your question with the pieces of code you showed, but how are you saving and getting the values of the database? And how are you going back from activity C to activity B / A?

Comment: I am saving data with database class and related-working methods of main class with it.Actually this application is User-Profile Application in which user can edit and can see Profile. So Main Activity contain one Button Named "Profile" when user click on it. It moved to his profile(that is Activity B) with edit Button below the profile.and when user Click on Edit button he moves to Activity C to edit the profile Suppose i am saving value on Activity C like:
"(TextView)Name
(EditText)Jack"
and then i am showing these values on Activity B like:
 "(TextView)Name
(TextView)Jack"

Comment: Below Activity B,I am having button to Edit which moved User to edit the Profile through Activity C. Hopefully you get it ?

Comment: I've understand your workflow, but I want to know how are you moving from activity C to B. Are you saving the data on database and closing the activity? If yes, the data on ActivityB is really realoaded? Or its the values that you've input before? I dont think that there is a problem with your activity workflow. My guess is that there is an error on your database save/retrieve logic, and the data on your Activity B is only right because its not refreshed.

Comment: In Simple Words I have Main Activity with Button Named "Profile".Clicking on Button moved User to Activity B that is Showing Profile of user.But In Starting it is empty so user have to fill it,Right ? SO there is button below profile that says "edit" Clicking that button lead user to Activity C where he can edit or put the data and When User clicked Save Button. Data get Saved as toast notify me. Now there is another button too in Activity C that says "Back to Profile" if User pressed that User Move to his Profile View(Activity B),information that he stored by clicking save Button is being++

Comment: ++shown on Activity B from database. I can see that information in profile if i click button
"back to profile" but if i move further back to main activity then  come back again
click button "profile" everthing get losted. I want that everytime i come to activity B
that is showing profile,Saved Data come from database and shows me to the Profile that 
user already Submitted.

Comment: if you can post you complete code we will be able to modify it or suggest any alternatives with the peace of code here it is unclear how you have implemented it in your code

Comment: I pasted code. Actually i guess when i come back to mainactivity that is Activity(A). and tries to reload intent-activity again. i dont get data that is stored in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using a CursorLoader to keep you views data fresh when navigating through your activity stack.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Comment: Thank you Mr. Larry But Do you have Some Sample Code implementing this Concept Cursor Loader. I didn't used it before.